# JQuery: How to select other elements based on their relationship with an element represented by the this key-word?

Tags: jquery

I've a few titles and a divs that wraps the content related to each title. when the page loads, I add a **plus image** inside each header-title. I also, hide divs with their content. When user clicks the title, I'd like (1)to change plus image into minus image and (2) display the div and their content.

```
$(function () {
    $("h6.blue").append(" <img src='../../Content/images/Effects/plus.gif' />");
    $("h6.blue+div").hide();
    //
    $("h6.blue").click(function (event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
         //Add code here...   
        }
    });
});
```

Above it was easier to write **$("h6.blue+div")** from **$("h6.blue")**. But with a **this** key-word arround, how do I do it? Can I do something like the code below?

```
if (this == event.target) {
        $(this + "div")...   
}
```

In fact, I want to select the div which is the direct sibling of the **h6.blue** contained in the **this**.

**EDIT**

Below is the Html code

```
<h6 class = "blue">My fisrt Title</h6>
<div>
     Content here...
</div>
<h6 class = "">My second Title</h6>
<div>
   Content here...
</div>
 And so on...
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Show sample HTML as well, please =)

Comment: @Sir Robert: Look at the HTML code above

Comment: Take out the `if (this == event.target)` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).next('div');
```

Depending on exactly what you're trying to select, use one of the sibling-traversing functions, such as:

- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next)
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)
- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll)

---

Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5JffG/

Comment: I'm trying to select the next element to the this (in this case, the h6.blue). The next element is div. First, I hide it, then I display it after the user clicks <h6> element.

Comment: @Richard: see my edit. It works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5JffG/

Comment: @Matt: I see why it was not working. In fact, I was clicking the plus image instead of clicking the text. when I click the text then it works. But, why it's works for the text not for the image, yet the image is inside the <h6>????

Comment: @Richard: clicking the image _still_ works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5JffG/1/ What browser are you using?

Comment: That's strange. because I've just copied and pasted your code (which is not that different from mine), but I can't still get the effect by clicking on the image.

Comment: @Richard: perhaps you could make a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem? You say "not that different," I say "the devil is in the details (tomahto)"

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. I just saw the your above recommendation telling me to remove if(event.target == this). Now I can click on the image and get the result. Thanks

Comment: @Richard: you're welcome. Also, it's not strictly necessary to `@username` someone when you're commenting on their question or answer - they'll be notified without it. The real value of the `@username` notifications is when you're replying to a comment made by someone other than the user whose question/answer you're adding the comment to.

Comment: @Richard: no worries! Just trying to be helpful; that's what SO is all about after all :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried...

```
$(this).next("div")
```

Comment: I've done this: $(this).next("div").show(), but is not working.

Comment: @Richard: you've got to provide more detail than simply "is not working." Have you tried using [a debugger](http://getfirebug.com)? Is it `.show()`-ing the wrong element?

Comment: Look at the question. the first 2 lines of code work perfectly, i.e. the appropriate elements are hidden when the page loads. But when I click the title, the content inside the div are not displayed.

Comment: I agree with Matt Ball's comment above--have you gotten rid of the check against event.target?